Как сделать проверку в Unity какая текущая сцена и загружать ту сцену которая указана в коде
Вот мой код
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
     private Vector2 targetPos;
     public float Yincrement;
     public float speed;
     public float maxHeight;
     public float minHeight;
     public int health = 3;
     private void Update()
     {
          transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
          
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && transform.position.y < maxHeight)
          {
               targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Yincrement);
          }
          else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && transform.position.y > minHeight)
          {
               targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Yincrement);
          }
          if (health <= 0)
          {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoseNormal");
          }
     }
}

я хочу что бы например если health <= 0 то мы получаем активную сцену и если эта сцена например GameNormal то загружаем сцену LoseNormal

SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name - выведет название сцены
     if (health <= 0)
     {
         if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "GameNormal")
         {
              SceneManager.LoadScene("LoseNormal");
         }
     }


Можно пожалуйста пример кода? Просто я немного невдупляю куда это писать

Добавил пример в ответ

Спасибо! Всё сработало

можно if (health <= 0 && SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "GameNormal")
